# How do I create a H2 database with the date data type

Tags: h2

I am trying to create a database in H2 (version 1.4.199), I need to include the date data type which is causing me issues when creating the database.  I get a 50004 unknown data type error.

Can anyone advise where I am going wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chapter (
CHAPTER_ID long,
STUDENT_ID long,
DATE - FORMAT yyyy-mm-dd,
UNIQUE (DATE),
PRIMARY KEY (CHAPTER_ID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table definition is not valid, it should be

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chapter (
    CHAPTER_ID BIGINT,
    STUDENT_ID BIGINT,
    DATE DATE,
    UNIQUE (DATE),
    PRIMARY KEY (CHAPTER_ID)
);
```

or something like it.

Comment: Thanks changing my statement syntax to DATE DATE solved the issue :)